# how to make HTTP request over local area network?

Tags: java, android, http, servlets, lan

I have Android app (API 14 and running on smartphone with Android 4.4) and java server both connected to same LAN but running on different machines.

This is the code in servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    handleRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    handleRequest(request, response);
}

private void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.getWriter().write("yes!!!");
}
```

And this is the code Android app uses to make HTTP GET request:

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.200.10.66:8080/myServer/myServlet"); //this is server's LAN IP I got from ipconfig
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())); //The app will indefinitely block here
String response = readUntilEndOfStream(br);
br.close();
```

Both Android app and java servlet work separately. I use the same Android code to make HTTP GET request to a Google's web service. If I do `http://10.200.10.67:8080/myServer/myServlet` from server machine's browser I get the expected result:

[image]

But if I do the same request from any other machine on the LAN, I get 'Web page not available'.
If Android app makes the request, it will indefinitely block on `con.getInputStream()`.

How to make requests over LAN work? Does it have something to do with the LAN router?

Comment: What does not work? As long as both systems are on the same subnet and no firewall is blocking, it should just work straigt forward

Comment: I can't see your question could you please clearify what your question and problem is?

Comment: Could you paste your android version and is LTE enabled? if >5.0 and LTE ready, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html maybe useful.

Comment: Android app will block indefinitely block on getInputStream(). Also if other machines on the LAN make http://10.200.10.67:8080/myServer/myServlet request from their browsers they will get 'Web page not available'

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that smartphone was connected via wifi and server via cable putting them in different subnets.